# Is there any way to find exact boundaries of an image in cocos2d instead of making a rect of that image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I want to cut a part of large image with the shape of a small image. Is there any way to find the exact shape of small image instead of making rect of that image using boundingBox?  Please reply..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it by masking the bigger sprite with the smaller one.

Here you have a great tutorial on that:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4421/how-to-mask-a-sprite-with-cocos2d-1-0

And here is the tool that they use to play with the blending functions

http://www.andersriggelsen.dk/glblendfunc.php

Comment: Thanks Lio. The above tutorial is really helpful. But,is it possible to trace the intersection of a sprite with the exact boundaries of that masked sprite?